# Storyboard weird controller view frame origins

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa

I have ran into a weird issue with Xcode-s storyboards.

I have a good amount of view controllers in my board, and for some reason all of their view's origins are not 0. All of x origins are 160 and y origins are 240.

[image: This is one of the view controller's view]

All of the views look like they are still on top-left..

Weird thing also is that most of the view controller's subviews seem to have wrong coordinates as well.

[image: This is a top view subview]

Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Comment: Try to clean you project or restart you Xcode or restart your compute? Sometimes Xcode does not works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing here is that `X` in your example is not top-left referenced but center. Just click the top left dot in the inspector (origin) and you should see the 'correct' values. [image]

Comment: This is a great answer! That red cross should be on the upper left corner.

Answer (score 0):

Select the view controller then  go to Attribute Inspector set size as "FreeForm"