# X & Y coordinates of the main UIView are not 0,0 in interface builder

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storyboard weird controller view frame origins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13191941/storyboard-weird-controller-view-frame-origins)

in the following screenshot, the main view's X & Y coordinates are supposed to be 0,0 (because it's simply the main view that sticks by default to screen bounds) why do they appear as 160, 294 ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this Screenshot you can get the answer from this screenshot[image: See the screenshot of xcode]